# How to distribute Image folder?

Tags: cocoa, bundle

I have a sandboxed osx app which contains a huge number of logos as png-files.
If there are any logos missing, the app downloads the missing logos automitcally from the web.
Because the app is sandboxed, all logos are stored in a folder in  `Library > Applikation Support`.

My question is now, how I could distribute the already existing logos with an app bundle?

The best way would be, if the app launches the first time, the logo-folder inside Application Support gets created and all Logos are copied from the bundle inside the new folder.

Is this possible with an app bundle or do I have to create an installer?
Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: "Because the app is sandboxed, all logos are stored in a folder in Library > Applikation Support."  It doesn't sound right.

Comment: What have you tried so far? (Yes, this is possible.) BTW: What is the advantage of distributing some logos inside the app bundle. It has to be downloaded either way.

Comment: @AminNegm-Awad The advantage is, that not all 2000 logos have to be downloaded on first start. The download function is only for update purpose, if some logos are missing.

Comment: @ElTomato Why doesn´t it sound right?

Comment: You completely misunderstand the concept of sandboxing an application.  If you could access the Application Support folder, then what's the point of sandboxing it in the first place?

Comment: @JoschHazard With this argument you simply delay the app start, because the download of the app itself takes longer. Th 2000 logos *are* downloaded before app start: When the app is downloaded.

Comment: @ElTomato - The OP might well be storing the images in `Library/Application Support`, just within the apps container - which of course it does have access to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's see if we can round out the comments you've received so far.

> My question is now, how I could distribute the already existing logos with an app bundle?

**Short answer:** just include them in the bundle as resources. Many applications include images for use in their GUI the only difference you have is maybe its a "huge number".

**Long answer:**

Here is the outline one way to do it:

1. Create a *Group* in Xcode, say `Logos`, which is associated with a folder (in Xcode 9 `New Group` generates the folder, prior to that you can create the folder-less *Group* and then use the *File Inspector* to add one).
2. Add your logos to this group. **Do not** mark these images as part of your target (otherwise Xcode will copy and flatten your folder structure)
3. Add a *Copy Files* or *Run Script* *Build Phase* to copy the images to a subfolder of `Resources`, say `Logos`.

As the images are part of your app bundle you can access them directly from there using standard bundle and file routines. There is no need to copy them anywhere.

Finally you managed to cause some confusion with the statement:

> Because the app is sandboxed, all logos are stored in a folder in  `Library > Applikation Support`.

It is unclear which folder you mean here, there are three obvious candidates:

1. System: `/Library/Application Support`
2. User: `~/Library/Application Support`
3. Sandboxed App: `~/Library/Containers/<bundle id>/Data/Library/Application Support`

If you are using the APIs (`URLsForDirectory:inDomains:`, `URLForDirectory:inDomain:appropriateForURL:create:error:`, `NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains`), request the user domain, and are in a sandboxed app then (3) is returned instead of (2) and your sandboxed app has access to it with asking permission from the user.

A subfolder of `Application Support` (whichever one you use but (3) is recommended), typically named according to the bundle ID of your app, is the place you should store logos your app downloads – there is no need to copy images you include in your app bundle into the same location.

HTH

Comment: Thank you very much, I think I can work with your answer very good!